# Are multiple subqueries needed to select max from 2 fields in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am relatively new to SQL.  I believe I need multiple sub-selects in my Oracle query to achieve the results I am interested in, but I have been unable to get the query to work correctly.

I need to pull the base data from the "Customer" table, and pull additional data from a second table "Customer_Issue".  There are additional tables that contain other fields I need, but I have successfully joined/selected that data through joins to the "Customer" table

The data I need from "Customer_Issue" are in the fields "Service", "Service_Issue", and "Service Version".  There are multiple service issues for each service, and multiple service versions for each service issue.

For each service, I need to select only the max Service Issue, and for that selected service issue, I only need to select the max service version.

Through a sub-select, I have been able to select the max service issue as follows:

```
Select c.customer_id, ci.service, ci.service_issue
from customer c
left outer join CUSTOMER_issue ci on c.CUSTOMER_ID = ci.CUSTOMER_ID
join (select CUSTOMER_ID, service, max(service_ISSUE) as service_ISSUE
from CUSTOMER_issue
group by CUSTOMER_ID, service) ci1
on ci1.CUSTOMER_ID = ci.CUSTOMER_ID and ci1.service = ci.service
and ci1.service_issue = ci.service_issue
```

However, I cannot get a subsequent sub-select to work to obtain the max service version.  Here is what I have tried (in the query, it is directly below the code above)

```
join (select CUSTOMER_ID, service, service_ISSUE, max (service_VERSION) as service_VERSION
from CUSTOMER_issue
group by CUSTOMER_ID, service, service_ISSUE) ci2
on ci1.CUSTOMER_ID = ci2.CUSTOMER_ID and ci1.service = ci2.service and
ci1.service_ISSUE = ci2.service_ISSUE and ci1.service_VERSION = ci2.service_VERSION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want the highest version on the highest issue.  I'm not absolutely sure, but that is how I'm interpreting the question.

If so, the best solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
select  c.customer_id, ci.service, ci.service_issue     
from customer c left outer join
     (select ci.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ci.customer_id, ci.service
                                order by service_issue desc, service_version desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from CUSTOMER_issue ci
     ) ci
     on c.CUSTOMER_ID = ci.CUSTOMER_ID and
        ci.seqnum = 1
```

For each customerid/service combination, it enumerates the issues, based on the `order by` clause.  The highest issue will get "1" for its highest service_version.  My guess is that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work to fix your subquery issue if I'm understanding your requirements:

```
SELECT 
    c.customer_id, 
    ci1.service, 
    ci1.service_name, 
    ci1.service_issue, 
    ci2.service_version
FROM customer c
    JOIN (
        SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, service, service_name, max(service_ISSUE) as service_ISSUE
        FROM CUSTOMER_issue
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, service, service_name
        ) ci1 ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = ci1.CUSTOMER_ID
    JOIN  (
        SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, service, max(service_VERSION) as service_VERSION
        FROM CUSTOMER_issue
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, service
        ) ci2 ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = ci2.CUSTOMER_ID AND ci1.service = ci2.service
```

There may be a simpler approach depending on your needs.